# Cannot specify compile options for imported target "..."

Tags: cmake

I want to provide the users of my library with two targets: one that specifies the include path etc., and one that carries useful extra compile options. However, for the extra target some of my users are getting the error

```
Cannot specify compile options for imported target "myproject::extra"
```

so it seems on older CMake versions.

> I tested with CMake 3.9.2. The test project, including CI is on [GitHub](https://github.com/tdegeus/test_cmake), with failing build [here](https://travis-ci.com/tdegeus/test_cmake/jobs/278351449).

**(How) can my approach be rendered robust for all CMake versions?**

---

The project's main `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(myproject)
add_library(myproject INTERFACE)
set(MYPROJECT_VERSION "1.0.0")

target_include_directories(myproject INTERFACE
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
include(GNUInstallDirs)

install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/" DESTINATION include)
install(TARGETS myproject EXPORT myproject-targets)
install(EXPORT myproject-targets FILE myprojectTargets.cmake DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/myproject")
write_basic_package_version_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myprojectConfigVersion.cmake" VERSION ${MYPROJECT_VERSION} COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion)
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/myprojectConfig.cmake" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myprojectConfigVersion.cmake" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/myproject")
```

The project's `myprojectConfig.cmake`:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

if(NOT TARGET myproject)
    include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/myprojectTargets.cmake")
endif()

if(NOT TARGET myproject::extra)
    add_library(myproject::extra INTERFACE IMPORTED)
    if(MSVC)
        target_compile_options(myproject::extra INTERFACE /W4)
    else()
        target_compile_options(myproject::extra INTERFACE -Wall)
    endif()
endif()
```

---

The user's project `CMakeLists.txt` could then look as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(myexec)
find_package(myproject REQUIRED)
add_executable(myexec main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexec PRIVATE myproject myproject::extra)
```

Comment: `on older CMake versions` - can you specify which version exactly? Are you sure that the error you are showing comes from this snippet? The "Cannot specify _link libraries_" looks like from `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: Why users ever need to link the library `myproject::extra`, which is IMPORTED, to something else? Could you show the line which performs that linking?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for your clarifying questions. I get failures on CMake 3.9.2. I have converted the question, and included a minimal example on [GitHub](https://github.com/tdegeus/test_cmake) that has the [failing CI](https://travis-ci.com/tdegeus/test_cmake/jobs/278351449).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for you clarifying question. I have included an example of the user's project and I have included the minimal example on [GitHub](https://github.com/tdegeus/test_cmake) that has the [failing CI](https://travis-ci.com/tdegeus/test_cmake/jobs/278351449).

Comment: The IMPORTED target support to `target_compile_options` was added somewhere between cmake 3.10 to 3.11. Can't you just use another name`add_library(myproject::extra_the_file STATIC IMPORTED) # or SHARED?
        add_library(myproject::extra INTERFACE)` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk Just changing to `add_library(myproject::extra STATIC IMPORTED)` fails (I get some vague Makefile error when building the project). Changing to `add_library(myproject::extra SHARED)` or `add_library(myproject::extra INTERFACE)` gives CMake errors (The target name "myproject::extra" is reserved or not valid for certain CMake features, such as generator expressions, and may result in undefined behavior.)

Comment: Haven't you tried to create `add_library(extra INTERFACE)` in **your project**, `install` that target and let CMake to generate an export file for it? In any case, as `target_compile_options(INTERFACE)` affects only on the property `INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS`, you may **set** this **property directly**. This is supported in any CMake version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of functions applicable for IMPORTED and INTERFACE targets changes as CMake evolves.

Most of such functions affects only on specific *target properties*. So, instead of calling a function, you may set the property directly. This will work in any CMake version:

```
# Works only in new CMake versions
target_compile_options(myproject::extra INTERFACE /W4)
# Equivalent which works in any CMake version
set_property(TARGET myproject::extra PROPERTY INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS /W4)
```

Comment: Actually... CMake bugs on the `add_library(highfive_deps INTERFACE)` line. What do you propose as version independent strategy?

Comment: What do you mean by "CMake bugs"? CMake 3.0 supports INTERFACE libraries and this is clearly stated in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html).